# Why is it recommended for a middleware to be async in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, middleware

Why is it recommended for a middleware to be async in ASP.NET Core?

E.g. in [this](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/core/how-to-add-custom-middleware-aspnet-core) tutorial it is recommended to make the middleware custom and I can not understand the reason behind it.

```
public class MyMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILoggerFactory logFactory)
    {
        _next = next;

        _logger = logFactory.CreateLogger("MyMiddleware");
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("MyMiddleware executing..");

        await _next(httpContext); // calling next middleware

    }
}

// Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.
public static class MyMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what your issue with it is. You don't have to async/await if you are doing sync code, thats also what the linked article says. You just return the delegate ratehr than await it if your code is async (and doesn't require `await`ing the code), i.e `return _next(httpContext)` instead of `await _next(httpContext)` (and then also remove the async from the method declaration)

Comment: If you just use `async`/`await` without having truely async calls inside, you just unnecessary cause a state machine (`async/await` generates a statemachine which handles the async code execution). I don't know where you did read "recommended" on that website, its not mentioned anywhere. Recommendation has always been, if you call  async code use `async/await`, if not don't and return the task unless you need to handle exceptions thrown by the async delegate/method (try/catch won't work with `return _next(httpContext)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the documentation, that is by design

> The middleware class must include:
>
> - A public constructor with a parameter of type `RequestDelegate`.
> - A public method named `Invoke` or `InvokeAsync`. This method must:
>
>   - Return a `Task`.
>   - Accept a first parameter of type `HttpContext`.

#### Reference [Write custom ASP.NET Core middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write)

My understanding is that the pipeline has been designed to be async by default.

`RequestDelegate` which is the core of asp.net core's pipe line requires a `Task` in order to allow a high-performance, and modular HTTP request pipeline.

```
public delegate System.Threading.Tasks.Task RequestDelegate(HttpContext context);
```

*From Comments:* credit to @ScottChamberlain

> The reason is that with how async was built in to asp.net core it allows for more throughput of web requests for the same hardware when comparing to a non async version.

Comment: So, just by design then. Yes?

Comment: @qqqqqqq Yes that is how Microsoft designed it.

Comment: @qqqqqqq if you are looking for more of a "why" the reason is that with how async was built in to asp.net core it allows for more throughput of web requests for the same hardware when comparing to a non async version.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I'll quote that into the post.

Comment: if you make it async then it can execute other stuff on the same thread while its waiting, if you make it sync then you're blocking a thread. I'd also argue that this doesn't matter in 99.9 % of all cases, especially if your code will only run for a ms or two.